# how to write connect statement of lineEdit in different class

Tags: linux, qt

How can I make signal and slot of `lineEdit` which is declare in another class ?
`LineEdit` is declared in `Peakdetechtion` class and i want to make signal and slot in `peaksettingform` so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the QLineEdit either has to be accessible from the outside (public or get) or you have to forward the signal you are interested in.

accessible version (incomplete and very dirty)

```
class Peakdetechtion { // horrible name
public:
  QLineEdit* getLineEdit() { return m_lineEdit; } // don't do it

private:
  QLineEdit* m_lineEdit;
};

class Peaksettingform : public QObject { //horrible name
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Peaksettingform(Peakdetechtion *p, QObject *parent = 0)
  : QObject(parent) {
    // you can do this from outside and replace 'this' with a pointer to a Peaksettingform object 
    connect(p->getLineEdit(), SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(handleText(const QString &))); 
}

public slots:
  void handleText(const QString &);
};
```

signal forwarding

```
class Peakdetechtion : public QObject { // horrible name
Q_OBJECT
public:
  Peakdetechtion() {
    m_lineEdit = new QLineEdit(); // should have a parent but i am lazy
    connect(m_lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)), this, SIGNAL(leTextChanged(const QString&)));
  }

signals:
  void leTextChanged(const QString &);

private:
  QLineEdit* m_lineEdit;
};

class Peaksettingform : public QObject { //horrible name
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Peaksettingform(Peakdetechtion *p, QObject *parent = 0)
  : QObject(parent) {
    // you can do this from outside and replace 'this' with a pointer to a Peaksettingform object 
    connect(p, SIGNAL(leTextChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(handleText(const QString &))); 
}

public slots:
  void handleText(const QString &);
};
```

Comment: Accessible version is not wokring . . .  can you figure out why? @Lifeisabug

Comment: @GiridhariLal -- What do you mean "is not wokring"?  Explain the problem symptoms.

Comment: The code I provided obviously isn't compilable. It merely was a demonstration on how you can approach that issue. You either have to connect to the line edit directly which menas it has to be accessible from the outside, or you can forward the signals you need and connecto to those forwarded signals from the outside.